# Saving Insertions into a database

Tags: c#, sql

I am updating a database using C# & SQL. When I insert a value into the table it exists in the table until I close the connection. How do I save the values that I inserted? Here is the code that I am using:

```
        conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;  AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Unmapped.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";            
        string sql = "INSERT into unmappedTeamsTable values ('Value1', 'Value2', 'PW')";
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        conn.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: You must have a transaction running - the code you show will not result in a rollback by itself

Comment: You are saving the values to the database. Do you mean how do you get the value back from the database once you have saved them?

Comment: Well, after I insert the values and view the table in the database it's empty!

Comment: But while the connection is open, you can see the data in SSMS or whatnot?

Comment: Does the code execute successfully?

Comment: The code executes successfully, and before I close the connection, when I run the command "SELECT TOP1 'xxx' FROM 'table' its there. But when the connection is closed and I open it later its not there anymore and the table is empty

Comment: I am using Visual C# and when I try to view the table data nothing is there

Comment: what do you mean by a transaction running?

Comment: First off you should be disposing of the connection. But otherwise I think BonyT is right, somewhere a transaction is coming into play (seems most likely anyway).

Comment: have you tried changing AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Unmapped.mdf to Database = Unmapped?

Comment: Hi thanks asdfg, that didnt work :(

Comment: Try the following around your code:

try
{
...
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
conn.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
}

Answer (score 0):

Set a brakepoint and see if your query is running or not.

I think your code is not executing properly.